# Measure in power bi

Tags: powerbi, measure, powerbi-desktop

I have this formula in qliksense now i want to do this power bi but this shows some error ..

I tried this

```
Total_Sales_Varaible = if('VBRK_BillingDocument_Header'[Billing Doc.currency_WAERK]="USD",SUM
```

but after sum i unable to do that

I have this code in qliksense

```
if([Billing Doc. currency_WAERK] = ('USD'),
sum({< Fiscal_Year = {'2016','2017'},[Billing Type_FKART] -={'ZG2','ZL2'}>}[Billing Sales Amount_NETWR])*vCurrency,
sum({< Fiscal_Year = {'2016','2017'},[Billing Type_FKART] -={'ZG2','ZL2'}>}[Billing Sales Amount_NETWR]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your source data structure isn't clear, but something like:

```
Total_Sales_Variable = 
IF ( 
    VALUES ( 'VBRK_BillingDocument_Header'[Billing Doc.currency_WAERK] ) = "USD",
    [vCurrency],
    1
) * 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( 'VBRK_BillingDocument_Header'[Billing Sales Amount_NETWR] ),
    FILTER ( 
        'VBRK_BillingDocument_Header',
        'VBRK_BillingDocument_Header'[Fiscal Year] = 2016 ||
        'VBRK_BillingDocument_Header'[Fiscal Year] = 2017
    ),
    FILTER ( 
        'VBRK_BillingDocument_Header',
        'VBRK_BillingDocument_Header'[Billing Type_FKART] <> "ZG2" &&
        'VBRK_BillingDocument_Header'[Billing Type_FKART] <> "ZL2"
    )
)
```

Comment: this shows an error  'VBRK_BillingDocument_Header'[Total_Sales_Variable]: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

Comment: As I said, it's hard to give a specific answer without seeing your data structure. Perhaps you could [edit] your question, to show a sample of your data, and what your expected output looks like?

Comment: i already paste code which is i used in qlik sense now i want to create that one in power bi ..